# go-gorm difference between db.Model and db.Table query

Tags: go, go-gorm

Which is the difference in go-gorm between `db.Model` and `db.Table` query.
One difference which I found, is while using `db.Table().Updates()`, is not updating the `updated_at` field by its own, and while using `db.Model` it does.

I don't know if is a bug or is the intended way, there are other differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.Model` is the ordinary way of doing things. It allows you to tell gorm which model struct this operation relates to. It isn't always needed, as for example a simple Find with the right struct type will infer the model automatically.

`db.Table` allows you to interact with tables that may not have a model struct, or to override the table for a given operation. It is lower-level and less convenient as it requires the code to know about a table name, which in normal ORM code you'd want to be automatically derived from the model name.

If you're seeing that `Table().Updates()` does not set the `updated_at` column, you might want to make sure you're running the latest version of gorm. Also, are you calling Updates with a model struct instance or with a map? (with a map it's unlikely that updated_at would be set).

Comment: Thank you, I am on the latest version and I am calling it with map.

Comment: Okay, then that explains it: With Table and Updates(map), gorm has no way to know that your model even has an UpdatedAt field to take care of.

Comment: `db.Model` uses `DeletedAt` in queries but `db.Table` don't.